# Zend Framework - Set No Layout for Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-controller, zend-layout

I have a Controller that I want to use for ajax scripts to call and set session variables, get information, etc. How do I set it so that that particular controller doesn't use the default layout (specifically NO layout) so that it can send XML/JSON messages back and forth?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like anything to do with Zend_Framework and Zend_Application, there are multiple ways to do this, but on the last few pure Zend gigs I've done, I've seen people using the following (from an action method in you controller)

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
```

This shuts off of the layout.  If you wanted to turn off your view as well, you could use

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

again, from an action method in the controller.

Answer (score 7):

in your controller ...

```
public function init() {
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // no Layout 
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        // no views
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller action, try

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```