# Zend - how to stop layout from rerendering?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've made an Ajax script that only loads (that's the plan) the content of the pages. The thing is it still reloads the whole layout, along with the views. How can I make it so it doesn't rerender when it already exists ?
My Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navigation li a').click(function() {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').hide('fast', loadContent);
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure based on your question, but does your AJAX code sit in a view?

This is a tricky one but I'd try this: in your given controller, you'd want to use a Zend-specific method call. Found this here at SO, it may apply.
[Zend Framework - Set No Layout for Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367601/zend-framework-set-no-layout-for-controller)

If you've already tried something similar to the above, perhaps this Zend Framework2 link would be of service: [Zend Framework 2: Auto disable layout for ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178632/zend-framework-2-auto-disable-layout-for-ajax-calls)

Comment: I call it in the layout script. I know it works because it does the hiding animation.

Comment: Were you able to do any disabling for this in the controller?

Comment: Ok. Also I noticed that the jQuery document.ready - inside there has a call to `window.location` and I'm not 100% sure - but it may be causing a reload that you speak of.

Comment: Perhaps try commenting out 1 or 2 lines of the ajax stuff (the window.location call might be causing the other functions to not get reached? Is there anything else happening based on your recent changes? Lastly - I'd maybe try doing the AJAX stuff in a view and not a layout - since you're calling methods that disable layouts

Comment: I deleted all that crap and just wrote `$('a').click(function() {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(toLoad);`
while adding a `setTerminal();` to all my controllers and it worked! The only problem now is that the URL stays the same, no matter the content, so I have to fix that somehow.